# Sending messages to QRadar using Python - any solutions?

Tags: python, configuration, soc, qradar

Send message to Qradar with Python

Hi everyone! Does anyone know how to use Python to send a message to QRadar? I need to write a function that takes json as an argument and sends it to the user's Qradar. Qradar REST API doesnt have an endpoint to send message. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.